# Call to a member function whereBetween() on integer in laravel 5.4?

Tags: mysql, where-clause, laravel-5.4

I am trying to use whereBetween between 2 different dates but I am getting an error "Call to a member function whereBetween() on integer". I am using bootstrap datepicker for getting 2 date inputs from the user. My code is below:

My form is below:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="start_date">From:</label><input type="text" name="startdate" id="startdate">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="enddate">To:</label><input type="text" id="enddate" name="enddate">
</div>
```

My query is below:

```
$client_ids = Array
              (
                 [0] => 1
                 [1] => 5
               )
$start = 2017-06-01;
$end = 2017-06-02;

$results = DB::table('lead_audit AS l')
             ->leftjoin('suppliers AS s', 's.id', '=', 'l.supplier_id')
             ->leftjoin('campaigns AS c', 'c.id', '=', 'l.campaign_id')
             ->select('s.name AS Supplier', 'c.name AS Campaign', 'l.disposition AS Disposition')
             ->count()
             ->whereBetween('l.received', [$start, $end])
             ->whereIn('l.client_id', $client_ids)
             ->groupBy('s.name', 'c.name', 'l.disposition')
             ->orderBy('s.name')
             ->orderBy('c.name')
             ->orderBy('l.disposition')
             ->get();
```

I googled it and I have tried a solution of "Wrap the dates in Carbon objects" like below
On top of my controller I have put this line "use Carbon\Carbon;" and changed the query at whereBetween is present like below:

```
->whereBetween('l.received', [new Carbon($start), new Carbon($end)])
```

But no luck again the same error as "Call to a member function whereBetween() on integer". I also have a doubt that is the above full query's order is correct or not? Can someone please help me what's wrong in this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `->count()` followed by the `->whereBetween()`.

The function `count()` gives you the number of rows of the `select()` so it returns an integer.

You have to remove the `->count()` and the query should work. If you want the number of rows from your query you can do the following:

```
$results = DB::table('lead_audit AS l')
         ->leftjoin('suppliers AS s', 's.id', '=', 'l.supplier_id')
         ->leftjoin('campaigns AS c', 'c.id', '=', 'l.campaign_id')
         ->select('s.name AS Supplier', 'c.name AS Campaign', 'l.disposition AS Disposition')
         ->whereBetween('l.received', [$start, $end])
         ->whereIn('l.client_id', $client_ids)
         ->groupBy('s.name', 'c.name', 'l.disposition')
         ->orderBy('s.name')
         ->orderBy('c.name')
         ->orderBy('l.disposition')
         ->get();
$num_rows = count($results);
```

> The query builder also provides a variety of aggregate methods such as `count`, `max`, `min`, `avg`, and  `sum`. You may call any of these methods **after** constructing your query.
>   **source:** https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#aggregates

Comment: First, Thanks for the quick reply. Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot once again.